# Cannot pass multiple attributes of an elements to a java script function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass the id and name attributes from below elements to handle Click event but only the id is being passed. When debugging name shows "undefined". Did I miss anything

```
function App() {
  const [id, setId] = React.useState('')
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('')
  const handleClick = event => {
    debugger
    setName(event.target.name)
    setId(event.target.id)
  }
  return (
    <form>
      <svg width="800" height="250">
        <rect onClick={handleClick} id="0" name="Rectangle" x="10" y="10" width="150" height="150" fill="green" />
        <circle onClick={handleClick} id="1" name="Circle" cx="300" cy="90" r="75" fill="red" />
        <polygon onClick={handleClick} id="2" name="Triangle" points="500,10 600,160 400,160" style={{ fill: "blue" }} />
      </svg>
      <Display id={id} name={name} />
    </form>
  )
}
```

Debugging screen shot below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const handleClick = event => {
    // debugger
    setName(event.target.id);
    setId(event.target.getAttribute("name"));
  };
```

demo 
https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-breeze-emiwc?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<rect onClick={(e) => {
     this.clickMe(e, {id: "0", name: "Rectangle"})
}}>Click Me</rect>
```

The function body

```
function clickMe(event, attribute){
     console.log(attribute.id);
     console.log(attribute.name);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. in order to avoid code duplication i used the getAttribute property as per above answer. cheers!